# Any way to pass additional parameters to Azure SQL Audit?

Tags: azure-sql-database, audit

We are exploring [Azure SQL Auditing capabilities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-auditing). It gives us a list of all the queries executed and some additional data which is good.

However, field `server_principal_name` is always reflecting a SQL username that is provided in a connection string. And it is always the same value - whatever was in the connection string.

We are running ASP.Net MVC application with Entity Framework for data access and there is a single connection string for the database, but there are multiple **application** users. It would be beneficial if we could see username of application user in audit rather than username of SQL user from connection string.

So my question - is it possible to pass parameters into Audit log in Azure SQL?

There is [similarly looking question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/112921/can-sql-server-audit-be-used-to-track-hostnames-or-ip-adresses-of-the-users-perf), but talking about DML, hostnames and IP. Answers seem to be saying "NO", but question is slightly different. Anybody can confirm that what I'm trying to do is (im)possible?